# Problem with running project on apache tomcat server

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I was trying to run a simple maven webapp project in eclipse on a localhost apache tomcat server.
When I try to run it this is the stack trace that I get:

```
mag 09, 2022 12:54:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [C:\Users\aless\Downloads\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
mag 09, 2022 12:54:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [C:\Users\aless\Downloads\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
mag 09, 2022 12:54:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [C:\Users\aless\Downloads\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
mag 09, 2022 12:54:02 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
AVVERTENZA: Problem with directory [C:\Users\aless\Downloads\lib], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:445)
```

(AVVERTENZA is italian for WARNING)

the folder that the warning points to doesn't exist, but I don't know how to change that.
If the ClassLoader needs the apache tomcat lib folder I have the Catalina Home set as an environment variable in the system but I don't know how to signal it.

I'll gladly add additional information if needed,
thanks in advance to everyone that will reply.

Comment: Run it how? Through Maven? Through Eclipse's Run on Server action?

Comment: through eclipse's run on server action

Comment: Do you have more of the console output? Something that explains why C:\Users\aless\Downloads\lib is important?